# filter functions problem

Tags: apache-flex, filter, filterfunction

I'm working on a search component for an app I'm working on and I needed to add some filters to it. I've found an example and got the first filter working fine.

Now I'm trying to add a second filter I'm running into problems... In the example I found they use filterFunctions, but I only get an option for filterFunction, why is that?

Here's the example code

```
   productsCollection.filterFunctions =
[
 filterByPrice, filterByType,
 filterByCondition, filterByVendor
]
```

And this is what I'm trying

```
acData.filterFunction = [filterByStatus, filterByDate]
```

but with this code I get the following error message - 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Array to an unrelated type Function.

Why am I getting this error and how would I go about add multiple filters to my Array Collection?

Thanks!

Comment: can you give us a link to the example you are working form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filterFunction` must be set to a single function, not an `Array` or any other datatype. To combine multiple functions create one that combines them, like this:

```
acData.filterFunction = function(item:Object) 
    {
         return
             filterByPrice(item) &&
             filterByType(item) &&
             filterByCondition(item) &&
             filterByVendor(item);
    };
```

If you saw a sample that used `filterFunctions` plural that accepted an array, post a link.  That's not anywhere in the standard Flex framework or in the new 4.0 beta afaik.

Comment: Thanks for the input Sam but I still seem to be having a problem

Comment: N/M I don't know what I was thinking. I got it figured out thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are going to have to extend an arraycollection to make it work.  this link should spell it out for you: http://blog.rotundu.eu/flex/arraycollection-with-multiple-filter-functions/